# Using Django Summernote without migration

Tags: django, summernote

Is there a way of using [django-summernote](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote) without applying the migration?

I am not using the attachment upload feature, so it's kinda useless for me to have a new table in my DB.

I think that it should be parametrized along with the `disable_upload` option as it looks like uploading is the only reason for having a migration.

Comment: I think any solution to your problem will require action from the django-summernote maintainers. I think in this case, you are better off opening an issue in [their github repo](https://github.com/summernote/django-summernote/issues).

Comment: Yep, I only created the question here to see if anyone has found a solution. If there isn't any, I'll open an issue.

Comment: Right. I'm not aware of any way to base the migrations for an app on a setting. I'd say the only solution is to move the models to an app within django-summernote. That would require one to add a second app to `INSTALLED_APPS` if attachments are needed.